# Как правильно спроектировать приложение

Tags: c#, проектирование

Есть у меня задача, а именно нужно сделать приложение, которое позволяет экспортировать данные из таблиц базы данных MS SQL Server NorthWind выполняя произвольные пользовательские SQL запросы. И нужно  заложить логическую структуру, позволяющую легко выполнять его дальнейшее развитие, модификацию и масштабирование.
Вопрос от меня, я не буду описывать то, что будет это все в паттерне mvvm, но вот такую логику приложения я вижу. Есть класс Контроллер, в нем два метода. Первый Отправляем_Запрос_в_Базу(). Второй Отображаем_результаты_выполнения_запроса() Хочу сделать этот метод отображения запроса так, чтобы я мог если нужно например отправить данные в файл csv или другой формат. И соответственно  класс Данные_в_csv,который пишет результат запроса в файл. Собственно сам вопрос. Как  сделать универсальную связку между классом Контроллер и классом Данные_в_csv так, чтобы при надобности я не изменял контроллер, а добавлял класс, нужный мне для вывода, то есть сейчас это  вывод в csv а потом может во что то другое понадобится, как это реализовать? Это через интерфейс, или это какой нибудь контейнер делать?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете что означают конкретные 2 слова в вашем техзадании? Почему бы не спросить это у тех, кто вам это ТЗ выдал?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы спрашиваете про шаблоны проектирования, загуглите singleton , MVC, MVP, MVVP и тд. и поймете что вам нужно. Мне кажется вам подойдёт MVC, или MVVP. Но если не знаете что это будет сложно.

Comment: @Dmitriy Спасибо за ответ, ноя знаю что такое MVC и тд.  Я думаю, что нужно предусмотреть возможность добавления новых запросов, изменения кода.

Comment: @AK Я вижу только один явно сформулированный вопрос - "Вопрос от меня, что имеется ввиду под модификацией и масштабированием." Он нормальный, не "слишком общий".

Comment: Это дословно-В приложении нужно заложить логическую структуру, позволяющую легко выполнять его дальнейшее развитие, модификацию и масштабирование

Comment: @AK Ну, вопрос туповат, конечно, но "туповатость" - это оценочное суждение. А по формальным признакам выделенный мной вопрос "нормальный".

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Так вопрос-то ваш в чем в итоге?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch `В приложении нужно заложить логическую структуру, позволяющую легко выполнять ...` - слишком размытая формулировка.

Comment: @Dmitry Вопрос такой, что имеется ввиду под модификацией и масштабируемостью. Вот дословно, что просят, В приложении нужно заложить логическую структуру, позволяющую легко выполнять его дальнейшее развитие, модификацию и масштабирование.

Comment: _чтобы при надобности я ... добавлял класс, нужный мне для вывода_ - плагинная система. Простой способ реализации описан у Рихтера CLR via C#. Так же гуглить по терминам MEF, MAF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за ответ, при этом мне ненужно будет переписывать и сам класс Контролллер, то есть я добавлю нужную мне функциональность вывода данных путем  написания нужного класса.

Comment: Да, можно будет даже не перекомпилировать (и не перезапускать) основное приложение. Лишь написать плагин/аддон и получившуюся либу поместить в нужную папку приложения. После чего можно будет использовать её (выбрав, например, в диалоговом окошке и т. п.)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да думаю это то что надо.